# cordeen or an ox tongue

Tags: meaning, slang

I'm having a hard time with the slang in the movie Focus. I have just heard the following line:

> All eyes on me until I make the mark. And once I fan him, I tug my lapel. Two fingers mean it's a prat poke. Three fingers mean it's an insider. If it's a cordeen or an ox tongue, I'll scratch my nose.

Context: the leader of a group of pickpocket thieves is giving instructions about how they will pickpocket people in the streets.

What do "cordeen" and "ox tongue" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

“Cordeen” and “ox tongue” are apparently real pickpocket slang for two types of pocketbooks, or “pokes”. Given the context, I would guess the type of poke affects the technique required to pick it without being noticed.

“Cordeen” is short for “accordion”. I can’t find a clear definition for “ox tongue”.